# Installing CERN ROOT on google Jupyter Notebook

Tags: google-colaboratory, root-framework

I have tried to install CERN ROOT http://root.cern.ch on google colaboratory Jupiter notebook https://colab.research.google.com. I can't get python running with ROOT, it crashes at:
import ROOT

I have been installing ROOT as usual:

```py
!mkdir -p APPS
!pwd
!cd APPS && wget https://root.cern/download/root_v6.16.00.Linux-ubuntu18-x86_64-gcc7.3.tar.gz 
!cd APPS && tar -xf root_v6.16.00.Linux-ubuntu18-x86_64-gcc7.3.tar.gz

!ls APPS/root/bin/thisroot.sh
!source APPS/root/bin/thisroot.sh
!echo $ROOTSYS
!echo $PYTHONPATH

import ROOT
```

The script APPS/root/bin/thisroot.sh should define PYTHONPATH and ROOTSYS variables, so this should allow to use ROOT from python.

PROBLEM:
After running this script the environmental variables are not set, so I can't run ROOT with my python.

So, how to setup these variables????

Thanks,
Marcin

Comment: You can update your PYTHONPATH using `sys.path.append('/content/root')`. But, the larger problem is likely that you are not building the actual deps. I'd recommend reading the [build quickstart docs](https://root.cern.ch/building-root#quick-start) in more detail.

Answer (score 1):

also I have tried to use ROOT on the google colaboratory Jupiter notebook, and I found that some libraries should be loaded before importing ROOT. The following code works at least in my notebook.

```
!mkdir -p APPS
!pwd
!cd APPS && wget https://root.cern.ch/download/root_v6.13.08.Linux-ubuntu18-x86_64-gcc7.3.tar.gz 
!cd APPS && tar -xf root_v6.13.08.Linux-ubuntu18-x86_64-gcc7.3.tar.gz

import sys
sys.path.append("/content/APPS/root/lib")
import ctypes
ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary('/content/APPS/root/lib/libCore.so')
ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary('/content/APPS/root/lib/libThread.so')
ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary('/content/APPS/root/lib/libImt.so')
ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary('/content/APPS/root/lib/libRIO.so')
ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary('/content/APPS/root/lib/libNet.so')
ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary('/content/APPS/root/lib/libTree.so')
ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary('/content/APPS/root/lib/libMathCore.so')
ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary('/content/APPS/root/lib/libMatrix.so')
ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary('/content/APPS/root/lib/libHist.so')
ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary('/content/APPS/root/lib/libGraf.so')
import ROOT

h = ROOT.TH1F("gauss","Example histogram",100,-4,4)
h.FillRandom("gaus")
c = ROOT.TCanvas("myCanvasName","The Canvas Title",800,600)
h.Draw()
c.Draw()
```

If you use the ROOT v6.16.00, you would see an error as below.

```
OSError: /content/APPS/root/lib/libImt.so: undefined symbol: _ZN3tbb10interface78internal20isolate_within_arenaERNS1_13delegate_baseEl
```

By the way, the versions of Ubuntu, gcc, and python of the google colaboratory are listed below.

```
Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS (Bionic Beaver)
gcc version 7.3.0 (Ubuntu 7.3.0-27ubuntu1~18.04) 
python 2.7.15rc1 (default, Nov 12 2018, 14:31:15)
```

Comment: If it helps, the default version on Colab is now Python 3 but pyroot is still compiled with python2.7 so a quick fix would be just to change the version on Colab

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the ROOT installation [instructions](https://root.cern/install/). If you compile ROOT with Python3 support you can then just import ROOT with `import ROOT`.